# Composer: Can I pick a package based on the processor architecture? 32bit vs 64bit?

Tags: php, 32bit-64bit, composer-php

I'm trying to let composer pick a package based on the processor's architecture.
For example, if the system is running 64bit, use the 64bit packages. Otherwise, use the 32bit ones.

Is this an existing feature?

Update: My use case is here: https://packagist.org/users/h4cc/

You can find multiple packages that are built for i386 and x64 architectures. I want to write one composer.json to handle both scenarios.

Comment: Commonly PHP includes are architecture-agnostic. They didn't see a use case, so don't [provide for](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md) this. What's your use case, btw?

Comment: I have never heard of PHP packages being written for a certain integer length. PHP does not make it easy to detect (apart from having PHP_MAX_INT constant defined, and switching over to float beyond). What is your use case?

Comment: UPDATE: Added a use case

Answer (score 0):

A given package can require the `php-64bit` package which will only make it installable on 64bit phps, but there is as of yet no specific php-32bit package, and the regular "php" package will be present for both 32 and 64 bit phps.

Comment: please look at my use case

Comment: Yeah ok. So you're shipping binaries with composer, not really the intended use case. One way you can somehow work around it is that both packages declare this: `"provide": { "wkhtmltopdf": "self.version" }`, then your users can require one of your wkhtmltopdf-amd64 or the other to satisfy the specific wkhtmltopdf dependency (that's the package other stuff should depend on, instead of the platform specific packages).